# How to Approve the Emails automatically

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder

How to Approve the Emails automatically when I create and save the Email in Salesforce Marketing Cloud (ExactTarget). Actually manually it is working but I need to automatically approve the emails once I created them.

Answer (score 3):

You need to disable *Approvals* in your account in order to enable sending unapproved emails. As far as I know automatic approval on a per user basis isn't available and if this feature is enabled, approval is needed:

> Enabling Approvals will allow you to review and approve emails. Unapproved emails can be edited, and only approved emails can be sent

So you could achieve this by disabling approvals, which can be done under *Administration -> Applications -> Approvals* (see [Enable Approvals](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/content_builder/approvals/how_to_enable_approvals/) in the documentation as this works quite the same).

**Further reading:**

- [Approvals](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/content_builder/approvals/)
- [Get started with Approvals](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/content_builder/approvals/getting_started_with_approvals/)
- [Enable Approvals](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/content_builder/approvals/how_to_enable_approvals/)

Comment: it is possible to approve the email  approval after some time mean schedule

Comment: At least I don't know of a possibility to do so. But I don't see a reason for having an approval process in place that automatically approves everything after a certain time. This wouldn't be any better than having no approval process at all. However I thought this could be possible using the REST-API and a cronjob, but unfortunately I couldn't find anything from having a quick look at the REST-Reference for Approvals. Just in case you want to have a look yourself, you can find it here: [REST API v1 Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/routes.htm)

Comment: i have another question it is possible to move the Data 
 exatension data to List without code

Comment: This isn't related to the the current question, so I suggest, you create a new one for your second question. If my answer to the current question helped, please mark it as accepted. Thank you!

Comment: @raviB As far as documentation is concerned there is no other option than the one I gave, so please mark my answer as accepted so others can easily see this has been answered. Thank you!